# Search pattern for range "0-255" in single atom for regexp in tcl

Tags: regex, search, pattern-matching, tcl

Can any one suggest me single atom pattern for the range 0-255 using regexp in tcl?

Comment: `(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])`  ?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Answer (score 1):

To match a number from 0-255 use:

```
\y(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])\y
```

`\y` ... matches at word boundary.